# Replacing Spaces in Sheets (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking to replace spaces in a variable to "%20".  Only the first space is being replaced.  I would like to replace all of them.

var Answer30Address = answer30.toString().replace(" ", "%20");

Comment: look at the highest score answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you use regex it will replace all, this should do.

```
var Answer30Address = answer30.toString().replace(/ /g, "%20");
```